# Elastic collisions inside a moving fence

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, angular-momentum, collision

A square, rigid fence of mass $M$ moves on a horizontal, frictionless plane. Inside it a point mass $m$ moves freely without friction. Assume the fence has initial velocity $0$ and that the particle has initial velocity $v_0$ forming an angle $\theta$ with one of the fence's sides. Determine the particle's trajectory if all collisions are perfectly elastic.

Notes: it is assumed that the fence cannot deform but can rotate.

There is no gravity.

It seems as if the solution involves writing down conservation of momentum on both axes, conservation of energy and conservation of angular momentum in the centre of mass frame, analysing the differences in the system's state before and after an individual collision, and remarking that the motion is periodical in the centre of mass frame. After trying this multiple times, most recently this morning, I have not one more clue about this problem than I had when starting.
Anything is appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps relevant: [Dynamic billiards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamical_billiards)

Comment: Why would you need to consider angular momentum? Are you supposed to assume the interaction forces between the ball and fence will have components parallel to the point of contact?

Comment: @BioPhysicist no need to assume any such thing. If the collision does not happen at the midpoint of a side, perpendicular force is sufficient to create torque

Comment: @carfog Sorry, I misread the problem